# Помогите с запросом на SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть задание

*Осуществить поиск  рейсов по дате, аэропорту, городу вылета. Вывести название аэропорта, города вылета, города прилета  по-русски, даты вылета и прилёта, упорядочить по номеру рейса, дате вылета, городу вылета.*

```
SELECT f.*, ad.airport_name->>'ru' AS Название_аэропорты, ad.city->>'ru' AS город_вылета, ado.city->>'ru' AS город_прилета, /* ТУТ ДОЛЖЕНО БЫТЬ ДАТА ПРИЛЕТА И ВЫЛЕТА И ПРИЛЕТА */
FROM flights f
INNER JOIN airports_data ad ON ad.airport_code = f.departure_airport 
INNER JOIN airports_data ado ON ado.airport_code = f.arrival_airport 
where DATE(f.scheduled_departure) = '2017-09-10' AND ad.airport_name->>'ru' = 'Домодедово' AND ad.city->>'ru' = 'Москва'
ORDER BY flight_no, /* ТУТ ДОЛЖЕНО БЫТЬ ДАТА ВЫЛЕТА*/ ad.city
```

У меня есть таблицы **airports_data: airport_code, airport_name, city** и **flights: flight_no schedule_departure, schedule_arrival, departure_airport, arrival_airport**

Я не знаю как вывести дата вылета и прилета? Можете помочь с этим.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: @wchistow простите не понял вас, о чем вы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*теперь на стаковерфлоу и переводами занимаются*

```
schedule_departure (дата вылета), schedule_arrival (дата прилёта)
```

Судя по вашему же описанию эти две колонки учесть в таблице flight (алиас f)

В вашем запросе без изменений эти две колонки должны выводиться, проверьте ещё раз (f.*)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]